# Handling partial/incomplete dates in .NET

Tags: .net, date

I have the need to handle partial dates, so for example:

- 1 April 2009 (stored as 1, 4, 200)
- Jan 2000 (Stored as null, 1, 2000)
- March 90 (Stored as null, 3, 1990)
- 00 (Stored as null, null, 2000)

and so on.

Looking at it, I don't think it's a massive problem as it will only have to handle UK dates, so globalization is not a consideration. The fiddly bit will be working out what a user means when they type 50, does that means 1950 or 2050.

Before I actually wade in and reinvent the wheel, has this been done before in some code that I can either use as reference or directly?

**Updates for Clarity**

The partial dates will be used to store the date of birth for people who are less than 25 years old.

As for how the data will be displayed:

User Enters: 01/00

Interpreted as: Jan/2000

Displayed as: Jan 2000

User Enters: 01/01/99

Interpreted as: 1/Jan/1999

Displayed as: 1 Jan 1999

Comment: What do you want to do with these dates?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Does Jan 2000 represent, say, Jan 1 2000 or does Jan 2000 represent all dates in January 2000?

Comment: They will be dumped into a sql database a 3 separate fields and will be stitched together for display. So when a user types in 3/00 we will pull out March 2000 and show that in the system.

Comment: You should clarify how all your examples should display.

Answer (score 1):

If we put these values through DateTime.Parse, then the only one that causes a problem is the last one, because it contains no date indication of any form:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("1 April 2009"));
// Outputs 01/04/2009 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("Jan 2000"));
// Outputs 01/01/2000 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("March 90"));
// Outputs 01/03/1990 00:00:00
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("00"));
// Throws an exception
```

However, putting Jan at the start of the last string gives us:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("Jan 00"));
// Outputs 01/01/2000 00:00:00
```

So, perhaps a slightly hacky solution is to regex match any string consisting solely of 2 or 4 numbers, and prefix it with the text "Jan"?

```
    String sample = "00";

    //check for 2 or 4 numbers in the string, nothing else 
    //except space before and after
    if (Regex.IsMatch(sample, @"^\s*(\d{2}|\d{4})\s*$"))
    {
        sample = "Jan " + sample;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(sample));
    // Outputs 01/01/2000
```

That will also work if sample is 00, 2000, or any other 2 or 4 digit (plus whitespace) strings.

The 3/00 string as indicated in your comment is a doozy, DateTime won't except it if it's prefixed with a 0, or if the "/" is replace with whitespace. 
What you need to do to that is check for a string containing a "/" followed by 2 digits, and then prefix those two digits with "20", resulting in "3/2000", which is parsed ok.

Annoyingly, the DateTime.Parse method does not allow for detection of null fields it found while parsing (it simply detected those as the start of the month/year).

---

Perhaps, as a UI suggestion, instead of trying to be too clever when putting into the database, while the user is typing in this crazy date string, parse it when the form (is it a web form?) is submitted. If the format is not immediately clear, suggest possibles to the user, like, did you mean 1950, or 2050?

Comment: Good UI suggestion. Validate date *as early as possible* and present it *to the person with the knowledge* right away.