# How to design Date-of-Birth in DB and ORM for mix of known and unknown date parts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, orm, date

Note up front, my question turns out to be similar to SO question [1668172](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668172/handling-partial-incomplete-dates-in-net).

---

This is a design question that surely must have popped up for others before, yet I couldn't find an answer that fits my situation. I want to record date-of-birth in my application, with several 'levels' of information:

- `NULL` value, i.e. DoB is unkown
- `1950-??-??` Only the DoB year value is known, date/month aren't
- `????-11-23` Just a month, day, or combination of the two, but without a year
- `1950-11-23` Full DoB is known

The technologies I'm using for my app are as follows:

- Asp.NET 4 (C#), probably with MVC
- Some ORM solution, probably Linq-to-sql or NHibernate's
- MSSQL Server 2008, at first just Express edition

Possibilities for the SQL bit that crossed my mind so far:

- 1) Use one nullable varchar column e.g. `1950-11-23`, and replace unkowns with 'X's, e.g. `XXXX-11-23` or `1950-XX-XX`
- 2) Use three nullable int columns e.g. `1950`, `11`, and `23`
- 3) Use an INT column for year, plus a datetime column for full known DoBs

For the C# end of this problem I merely got to these two options:

- A) Use a string property to represent DoB, convert only for view purposes.
- B) Use a custom(?) struct or class for DoB with three nullable integers
- C) Use a nullable DateTime alongside a nullable integer for year

The solutions seem to form matched pairs at **1A**, **2B** or **3C**. Of course 1A isn't a nice solution, but it does set a baseline.

Any tips and links are highly appreciated. Well, if they're related, anyhow :)

---

**Edit, about the answers**: I marked one answer as accepted, because I think it will work for me. It's worth looking at the other answers too though, if you've stumbled here with the same question.

Comment: Found another question asking a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668172/handling-partial-incomplete-dates-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The SQL Side**

My latest idea on this subject is to use a range for dates that are uncertain or can have different specificity. Given two columns:

```
DobFromDate (inclusive)
DobToDate (exclusive)
```

Here's how it would work with your scenarios:

```
Specificity   DobFromDate   DobToDate
-----------   -----------   ----------
YMD            2006-05-05   2006-05-06
YM             2006-05-01   2006-06-01
Y              2006-01-01   2007-01-01
Unknown        0000-01-01   9999-12-31
-> MD, M, D not supported with this scheme
```

Note that there's no reason this couldn't be carried all the way to hour, minute, second, millisecond, and so on.

Then when querying for people born on a specific day:

```sql
DECLARE @BornOnDay date = '2006-05-16'

-- Include lower specificity:
SELECT *
FROM TheTable
WHERE
   DobFromDate <= @BornOnDay
   AND @BornOnDay < DobToDate;

-- Exclude lower specificity:
SELECT *
FROM TheTable
WHERE
   DobFromDate = @BornOnDay
   AND DobToDate = DateAdd(Day, 1, @BornOnDay);
```

This to me has the best mix of maintainability, ease of use, and expressive power. It won't handle loss of precision in the more significant values (e.g., you know the month and day but not the year) but if that can be worked around then I think it is a winner.

If you will ever be querying by date, then in general the better solutions (in my mind) are going to be those that preserve the items as dates on the server in some fashion.

Also, note that if you're looking for a date range rather than a single day, with my solution you still only need two conditions, not four:

```sql
DECLARE
   @FromBornOnDay date = '2006-05-16',
   @ToBornOnDay date = '2006-05-23';

-- Include lower specificity:
SELECT *
FROM TheTable
WHERE
   DobFromDate < @ToBornOnDay
   AND @FromBornOnDay < DobToDate;
```

**The C# Side**

I would use a custom class with all the methods needed to do appropriate date math and date comparisons on it. You know the business requirements for how you will use dates that are unknown, and can encode the logic within the class. If you need something before a certain date, will you use only known or unknown items? What will `ToString()` return? These are things, in my mind, best solved with a class.

Comment: Interesting solution. Never thought about this before. I'll file this away for further use on projects that need to gradually set date precision!

Comment: Wow, great suggestion. With the (mentioned) exception of the situations where only MD, D, M are known, this would allow me to represent things quite well in the DB side, and as you mention the C# side can add to it as it pleases. Gonna have a night sleep over it first, but may very well go with this solution as the only exception coincides with the one scenario that's merely "nice" to have :) Tx @ErikE

Comment: Thought some more about this solution. Ran a few queries on my data, which showed I rarely ever have a month or day but not the year. So I'm skipping the "nice to have" requirement, and will try this solution. Thx again @ErikE, marked it as the answer.

Comment: Cool @Jeroen, I'm glad it will work for you. Be careful with inclusive/exclusive endpoints and proper use of = vs. >=.

Comment: It's been a year but I finally got around to giving this solution a spin in my hobby project. It works like a charm, with some help of an extra C# class for UncertainDate. Extra bounty coming your way once the 24 hr wait period for awarding is over!

Comment: @Jeroen Nifty! Glad it worked out, and that makes sense—if you were able to specify day or month without the year, how would you use it? Say you know a birthday is January 1 (no year), and you are querying for people older than 65. Won't help! If you keep a text version of any DOB knowledge that can be presented to users (say "Jan 1" is saved as a string in the record), later if they learn more (the age without knowing the whole DOB), they can put the pieces together. Please do let me know if you have further developments that would recommend for or against this. Would love to see your class.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of 3 int nullable columns and a struct of 3 nullable int in C#.

it does take some effort in db handling but you can avoid parsing around strings and you can also query with SQL directly by year or year and month and so on...

Comment: My first attempt was indeed just this one, it's very "honest" about the information you have or don't have. However, @ErikE's answer above is a great competitor as that's "honest" about the info as well :). Decisions, decisions... Either way: thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do is going to be messy DB wise. For consumers of these kind of dates, I would write a special class/struct which encapsulates what sort of date it is (I'd probably call it something like PartialDate), to make it easier to deal with for consumers- much like Martin Fowler advocates a [Money Class](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html).

If you expose a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) directly in C#, this could lead to confusion if you had a "date" of ????-11-23 and you wanted to determine if the customer was over 18 for example- how would you default the date, how would the consumer know that part of the date was invalid etc...

The added benefit of having a PartialDate is it will allow other people reading your code to quickly realise that they are not normal, complete dates and should not be treated as such!

**Edit**

Thinking about the Partial data concept some more, I decided to Google. I found that There is the concept of [Partial on Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Partial.html) and an [interesting PDF on the topic](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2006/po/po11.pdf&rct=j&q=Partial%20Date&ei=XA8BTu7nGcmohAfA97TADQ&usg=AFQjCNFGU61URrL171qn2ZCnSXrsC5OSxA&cad=rja), which may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the links @RichardOD, gonna have a look at those tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem...

I like solution 2B over solution 3C because with 3C, it wouldn't be normalized... when you update one of the ints, you'd have to update the DateTime as well or you would be out of sync.

However, when you read the data into your C# end, I'd have a property that would roll up all the ints into a string formatted like you have in solution 1 so that it could easily be displayed.

I'm curious what type of reporting you'll need to do on this data... or if you'll simply be storing and retrieving it from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry to much about how to store the date, I would still store the date within a datetime field, BUT, if knowing if some part of the date was not populated, I would have flags for each section of the date that is not valid, so your schema would be:

DBODate as Date
DayIsSet as Bit
MonthIsSet as Bit
YearIsSet as Bit.

That way you can still implement all the valid date comparisons, and still know the precision of the date you are working on. (as for the date, I would always default to the missing portion as the min of that value: IE Month default is January, day is the first, year is 1900 or something).

Comment: The reason I would try to stick closely to the datetime datatype is because you automatically get all the correct date checking features, like February 29, how many days in the corresponding month, etc.

Comment: @NB- I original had the same thought the DB. The question is when you don't know the year part- how do you know that Feb 29th is valid? You'd also need to default to a year that was a leap year to accomodate Feb 29 in the case where the year is unknown...

Comment: @RichardOD very good point. Any of these solutions will require some custom logic revolving around date validation. I am not envious of your problem! I still think the best way to do this would still be to have default values for each of the date fields. Interestingly enough, year 0004 was actually a leap year, which is handled by the DateTime2 datatype within SQL.

Comment: Tx for the response @N8. I'm not sure if I'll go for this one though as values in the date column would be incorrect on itself allowing me to make mistakes when querying (you're never sure what the date means without those bit fields).

Comment: Very true, I wish you the best of luck. Thanks for the interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, all of the solutions mentioned above do represent some kind of compromise.

Therefore, I would recommend to think carefully which of the 'levels' is the most likely one and optimize for that. Afterwards go for proper exception handling for the other rare cases.

I don't know whether reporting is an issue for you right now or may be later, but you might consider that as third dimension apart from the DB / C# issues.

Comment: Wups, hadn't even thought about reporting yet :O, may have to consider that too when deciding on what solution to pick!